# How can I convert this ABES ASCII/.dat file into a workable CSV file within R?

Tags: r, ascii

The [file](https://www.cdc.gov/healthyyouth/data/abes/data/ABEH2021_5_RECRUIT.dat) is clunky, and I cannot find a way to import a workable version into R. I've tried `read_csv()`, `read_delim()`, `readLines()`, and `readtable()`, but nothing seems to be able to work. Some columns seem to be delimited by periods and some seem to be delimited by white space. More information on the publicly available data set can be found [here](https://www.cdc.gov/healthyyouth/data/abes/data.htm)

Let me know if you're able to help - thanks!

Comment: when using readLines, how would you want the data to be structured? ie what will be the first column, 2nd column etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of the tidyverse and the SAS and SPSS scripts provided in the ABES documentation can be a timesaver here. For example, you can use the widths from the SPSS script with the `readr::read_fwf()` option `fwf_cols()`. For example, the first few columns to pass to `fwf_cols()` would look like this: `Q1 = c(1, 17), Q2 = c(18, 18), Q3 = c(19, 19))`. Once you have it working, you can check your frequencies against Appendix E in the ABES Data User's Guide.

Comment: thanks - can you provide some more clarity on how to combine the `fwf_cols` function with the actual .dat data?

Comment: This is how the start of my code looks but you'll obviously need to specify the widths for the rest of the columns: `df <- readr::read_fwf('ABEH2021_5_RECRUIT.dat', 
                      readr::fwf_cols(Q1   = c(1, 17),
                        Q2   = c(18, 18), Q3   = c(19, 19), Q4   = c(20, 20), 
                        Q5   = c(21, 28), Q6   = c(29, 32), Q7   = c(33, 38),
                        Q8   = c(39, 39), Q9   = c(40, 40), Q10  = c(41, 41),
                        Q11  = c(42, 42), Q12  = c(43, 43), Q13  = c(44, 44)) #more cols`